# MySQL strange characters replace with <BR

Tags: mysql

I inherited a MySQL table (MyISAM   utf8_general_ci encoding) that has a strange character looks like this in myPHPAdmin: •

I assume this a bullet point of some type?

When rendered on a HTML page it looks like this: �

How do I replace this value with a `<BR><LI>` so I can turn it into a line break with a properly formatted list item?

I've tried a standard UPDATE query but it does not replace these values?  I assume I need to escape them somehow?

Query attempted:

```
UPDATE `FL_Regs` SET `Remarks` = "<BR><LI>" WHERE `Remarks` = "•"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not showed your query, so I'm only guessing.

If you're having hard times with your client encoding characters for you (I imagine you may use phpmyadmin, which involve a lot of steps between your browser and the actual server), you may try by giving the string to search as sequence of bytes.

It happen that • is U+2022, a character named "BULLET" in Unicode, which is encoded as e2 80 a2 in UTF8. So you can use X'E280A2' instead of '•' in your query.

Typically:

```
> select X'E280A2';
+-----------+
| X'E280A2' |
+-----------+
| •         |
+-----------+
```

You can, if you want to better understand what's happening, try to use the HEX() function, first maybe to check what's MySQL is receiving when your're sending a bullet:

```
SELECT HEX('•');
```

Typically I'm getting `E280A2` which is as previously seen the UTF8 encoding of the BULLET character.

And so see what's actually stored in your table:

```
SELECT HEX(your_column) FROM your_table;
```

Try to limit the search to a single raw to make it almost readable.